# Using product rule to turn $\frac12$ $\frac{d}{dt}$ $x^2(t)$ into $x(t)x'(t)$

Tags: calculus

Part of a solution to a problem that I'm working on states that by the product rule, we can obtain the following:

$\frac12$$\frac{d}{dt}$$x^2(t)$ $=$ $x(t)x'(t)$

I have tried computing this on my own and I'm at a loss. I don't see how this can be done with product rule. Please, if someone can explain how this works I would be so grateful.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you mean [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)?

Comment: @AndrewChin yes this is what I figured they meant to say and I tried using chain rule but the square on the x is confusing me.

Comment: $x^2(t)$ here means $x(t) \cdot x(t)$. For some reason people keep writing this when they should write $x(t)^2$. I think you can see how the product rule comes in for $x(t)\cdot x(t)$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Okay yes that makes much more sense. So you CAN use product rule when it's written as $x(t)^2$

Comment: @eyeballfrog "...when they should write..." Actually, $x^2(t)=x(t)\cdot x(t)$ is fairly common, and used all over the pace, so it is standard. It is true that it can be used for $x(x(t)),$ but that is rarely needed. It does make the notation $x^{-1}(t)$ odd, however, since that always means the inverse function, rather than $\frac1{x(t)}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I didn't say it wasn't common. I said people shouldn't do it. This question is one of the many illustrations of why.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I prefer $x^2(t)$ to $x(t)^2,$ although of course $(x(t))^2$ is clearest. For some reason, $\cos(x)^2$ makes me want to rewrite it as $\cos(x^2)$ instead of $(\cos(x))^2,$ and I'm quite happy with $\cos^2(x),$ for the reason pointed out by Thomas Andrews.

Answer (score 3):

We have $x^2(t)= x(t) \cdot x(t)$ and therefore we have
$$\frac 12 \frac{d}{dt} x^2(t) = \frac 12 \frac{d}{dt} (x(t) \cdot x(t)) = \frac 12 \left (x'(t) x(t) + x(t) x'(t) \right )= x'(t) x(t).$$

Alternatively we can use the chain rule with the outer function $f(y)=y^2$ and get
$$\frac 12 \frac{d}{dt} x^2(t) = \frac 12 \cdot 2 x(t) x'(t)= x(t) x'(t)$$
because we differentiate a function of the form $f(x(t))$ where the outer derivative is $f'(x(t)) = 2x(t)$ and the inner derivative is $x'(t)$.

Comment: Alright yes I can see it now. I figured they meant chain rule. Thank you! Part of my confusion lied with the fact that I wasn't sure if $x(t)^2 = x^2(t)$